# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error in multi-dimensional array

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an array that would preferably store the object in this format `[[[String, CGPoint, Bool]]]`, but I get errors all over the place so I decided to set it as `[[[AnyObject]]]`.

Here is my code for declaring the array:

```
var savePlayerState:[[[AnyObject]]] = []
```

As you can see it's a multidimensional array, which I need to store 3 things: the current time, the player's location, and a simple Bool. Here is how I am trying to save the data to the array:

```
savePlayerState.append([timeLabel.text, player.position, isPlayerAlive])
```

My error is this:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I really am not sure what's going on, I have tried casting several different ways but I am stuck. I also do need to save all of these variables in an array, which I will be appending to every game loop and saving in a log for testing. How can I accomplish this? I feel like the solution is simple, I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually using `AnyObject` in Swift is the wrong approach unless it is required for interfacing to *Cocoa*/*Cocoa touch*.  You should probably use a custom structure to store `PlayerState` and then create an array of those:

```
struct PlayerState {
    var time: String
    var position: CGPoint
    var isAlive: Bool
}

var savePlayerState:[PlayerState] = []

savePlayerState.append(PlayerState(time: "10:05", position: CGPointMake(2.3, 2.4), isAlive: true))
savePlayerState.append(PlayerState(time: timeLabel.text, position: player.position, isAlive: isPlayerAlive))
```

---

You can implement the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol for your structure to make printing your log easier:

```
struct PlayerState: CustomStringConvertible {
    var time: String
    var position: CGPoint
    var isAlive: Bool
    var description: String { return "time: \(time), position: (\(position.x), \(position.y)), isAlive: \(isAlive)" }
}

savePlayerState.append(PlayerState(time: "10:05", position: CGPointMake(2.3, 2.4), isAlive: true))
savePlayerState.append(PlayerState(time: "11:03", position: CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0), isAlive: false))

for state in savePlayerState {
    print(state)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> time: 10:05, position: (2.3, 2.4), isAlive: true
> time: 11:03, position: (1.0, 1.0), isAlive: false
> ```

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution, fixed my issue immediately. Big props to both answers, both helped me massively. I selected this one as the accepted answer as it may quickly help others to fix their issue if they have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you actually want/need a multi-dimensional array. If you do absolutely need it to be a nested collection, please explain why.
The code below illustrates how your array works. (I made it an array of `Int` for simplicity)

```
var savePlayerState:[[[Int]]] = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]] // this a triple nested array
var firstNest = savePlayerState.first // [[1], [2]]
var secondNest = firstNest!.first // [1]
var thirdNest = secondNest!.first // 1
```

You can't append an `Int` to `savePlayerState` because it expects an element of type `[[Int]]`. One dimension less than itself.

In your code :

```
savePlayerState.append([timeLabel.text, player.position, isPlayerAlive])
```

You are appending a 1 dimensional array to a 3 dimensional array. Which does not work because it expects a 2 dimensional array. You are also not appending one object with three values, but three different values with different types.

Retrieving one specific value will be a nightmare.

This will work :

```
savePlayerState.append([[("someText", CGPointZero, true)]])
```

But it will still not be very useful.

Notice the `()` around the values. This will make the values into a `tuple`. Then you already at least have one element for each collection of values.

---

What you do want is an element that holds the three values. This can be a custom `struct` or `class`, but it can also be a `tuple`.

When working with `tuples` it is convenient to create a `typealias`

```
// this is a typealias to give the tuple a name
typealias aStringAPointandABool = (string:String,point:CGPoint,bool:Bool)

var tupleArray : [aStringAPointandABool] = []
var myTyple = (string:"SomeString",point:CGPointZero,bool:true)
tupleArray.append(myTyple)
```

---

```
// this is a struct with variables for the different values
struct myContainer {
    var string : String = ""
    var point : CGPoint = CGPointZero
    var bool : Bool = true
}

var myStructArray : [myContainer] = []
var myStruct = myContainer(string: "SomeString", point: CGPointZero, bool: true)
myStructArray.append(myStruct)
```

Comment: Wow this is some great info. I have only begun Swift as of this week so I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me. The reason why I want to use an array for the data is because I'm saving it in NSUserDefaults which as far as I understand, is easy to to use save/read arrays from. I'll try out the tuple solution, thanks :)

Comment: NSUserDefaults is very popular on SO these last few days. (this means a lot of people fail to use it lately) There are a couple of big ways to store data : CoreData, NSUserDefaults, plist,..  Look what is out there first before you start to implement something. Reading stuff takes little effort. Pulling your hair out, starting over and waiting for the hair to grow back is no fun.

Comment: user1547019 doesn't have enough reputation to upvote, but I'll do so for them.  Your answer contains much useful information.

Comment: @vacawama thx, returned the favour. Always forget to check rep, maybe that is a good thing.

Comment: @RMenke, I'll answer any question that is phrased well.  The up votes may follow days, months, or years later as it helps other readers.

Comment: @vacawama I know, I don't mind not getting the accept from time to time. The thrill of trying to get that perfect answer at the same time as someone else without cheating/stealing is most of the fun.

Comment: Yes.  And the competition improves all answers.  I've encountered much more friendly competition on SO than unfriendly competition.